# How to move large amount of qgraphicsitem efficiently?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have many qgraphicsitem which are waypoints on a map.
And I would like to move them together.
Thus I used a for loop to call their `setPos()` function.
But when the items number become large (over 100). 
The move becomes slow...
How could I make this more efficiently?

Comment: Do you call `setPos()` for each pixel during the move?

Comment: I called setPos for each QGraphicsItem during the move.

Comment: You can call setPos() only for the last position, when the move is done. For example, if you move items from point A to B, call setPos() for point B only and not for each points between A and B.

Comment: @vahancho that's not what OP is asking - OP is asking how to move several different items

Comment: @DrewMcGowen, no, he asks "How could I make this more efficiently?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're moving them all by the same amount, then you can use a [`QGraphicsItemGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemgroup.html) to group all of your waypoint items; then, you can simply move the item group to automatically move all the items in that group.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to try it out - if nothing else, it certainly won't be slower, and it'll help simplify your code.

Comment: @Nyaruko Yes this should be significantly faster as each `setPos(..)` call would previously trigger a scenegraph update (and probably a paint event, though there may be optimisations for that).  Moving a single parent item would cause a single scenegraph evaluation.